# Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read (PHP CODEIGNITER)

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-permissions, vercel

I am stuck with this error no matter what directory I am in. I use vercel for deploy, use codeigniter framework

---

```js
[22:47:40.765] Cloning github.com/johan-sar/myapi.tokojohan.org (Branch: main, Commit: 4119c36)
[22:47:41.978] Cloning completed: 1.213s
[22:47:42.359] Restored build cache
[22:47:42.414] Running "vercel build"
[22:47:43.076] Vercel CLI 28.10.0
[22:47:43.268] WARN! Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings
[22:47:43.293] > Installing Builder: vercel-php@0.3.1
[22:47:48.575]  Downloading user files
[22:47:48.576]  Downloading PHP runtime files
[22:47:48.580]  Installing Composer dependencies [START]
[22:47:48.815] [3.1MiB/0.00s] No lock file found. Updating dependencies instead of installing from lock file. Use composer update over composer install if you do not have a lock file.
[22:47:48.817] [3.2MiB/0.01s] Loading composer repositories with package information
[22:47:48.828] [3.4MiB/0.02s] Updating dependencies
[22:47:48.839] [3.6MiB/0.03s] Nothing to modify in lock file
[22:47:48.839] [3.6MiB/0.03s] Writing lock file
[22:47:48.839] [3.6MiB/0.03s] Installing dependencies from lock file
[22:47:48.840] [3.7MiB/0.03s] Nothing to install, update or remove
[22:47:48.845] [3.6MiB/0.03s] 1 package suggestions were added by new dependencies, use `composer suggest` to see details.
[22:47:48.845] [3.6MiB/0.03s] Generating autoload files
[22:47:48.846] [3.6MiB/0.03s] Memory usage: 3.63MiB (peak: 3.92MiB), time: 0.03s
[22:47:48.856]  Installing Composer dependencies [DONE]
[22:47:49.067]  Creating lambda
[22:47:52.711] Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.